# increment two indices at once

Tags: c, arrays

lets say I have two int arrays, array1 and array2.

Is this line:

```
array1[i++] = array2[j++];
```

equal to this:

```
array1[i] = array2[j];
i++;
j++;
```

?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent.

Comment: Before you get the answer, let me ask you, did you try to write a sample code and check the output? What did you get? Which part you din't understand?

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: What makes you believe that could be different?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I think OP haven't demonstrated *any* though or belief about it...

Comment: Smart ass job interview answer added below.

Comment: i'm new to c programming, just trying to learn

Comment: Get your favourite debugger out. That's a much better way to learn. Plus read a book. C is full of tricky corner cases.

Comment: @SouravGhosh If there are concerns about undefined behavior, which a novice might expect, trying it is not a good way to figure that out.

Comment: @dbush sorry, can't agree. 1) "Novice" is most likely to be unaware of UB 2) in case, UB is known, question should come in a form "why it does (not) work?"

Comment: @SouravGhosh: The idea is that he (she) doesn't know if it is UB and is asking if it is. Coding a simple example doesn't answer the question of UB because it may very well appear to work.

Comment: @R_Kapp Right, but that does not excuse the _lack of attempt_. Why it should (not) be UB, should be the first job of OP to find out. SO is not just "throw a q and enjoy the answer" _forum_, right? :)

Comment: Another minor difference is the first is 1 statement and the other is 3.  This makes a difference if the preceding was conditional/loop code like `if(foo)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they are equivalent, *unless* you've written `#DEFINE i j` or `#DEFINE j i`, in which case the behaviour of the first snippet is *undefined*.

Comment: That's a pity. I've just downvoted every answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318980/java-how-to-create-an-arraylist-of-integer-arrays?noredirect=1 and so need some karma.

Comment: Oh well, that's from me

Comment: ... and not both defines :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is allowed.  You're not modifying the same variable twice in one statement without a sequence point, so you're fine.

If you did this however, you'd invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

```
array1[i++] = array2[i++];
```

But this would be fine, since the comma operator introduces a sequence point:

```
array1[i++] = (j++,j++);
```

Comment: I can't agree that the second example is "fine"!  It might not be undefined, but it's unrealistic and confusing...